# Converting string into date returns wrong result

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have date in the form of string as `Mon, 18 Apr 2016 07:29:49 GMT` now i am trying to convert this into date object by doing this

```
NSDateFormatter *parsingFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[parsingFormatter setDateFormat:@"EE, dd MMM YYYY hh:mm:ss Z" ];
NSDate *date = [parsingFormatter dateFromString:@"Mon, 18 Apr 2016 07:29:49 GMT"];
```

But when i see the result in `date` object it contains following date `2015-12-21 07:29:49 +0000`

Can someone tell why it is changing the date from 18 apr 2016 to 21 dec 2015 ?

Answer (score 7):

`YYYY` is week-based calendar year.

`yyyy` is ordinary calendar year.

do like

```
NSDateFormatter *parsingFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[parsingFormatter setDateFormat:@"EE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss Z"];
[parsingFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
NSDate *date = [parsingFormatter dateFromString:@"Mon, 18 Apr 2016 07:29:49 GMT"];
```

**Swift**

```
let parsingFormatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
parsingFormatter.dateFormat = "EE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss Z"
parsingFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
let date: NSDate = parsingFormatter.dateFromString("Mon, 18 Apr 2016 07:29:49 GMT")
```

and you get the output of

[image]

Comment: always use ordinary calender year

Answer (score 5):

You are writing wrong date format it should be,

```
[parsingFormatter setDateFormat:@"EE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss Z" ];
```